# How do I evaluate relationships between 500 binary attributes and corresponding continuous score?

Tags: correlation, multivariate-analysis

I'm going to preface this all by saying that I'm pretty pedestrian when it comes to large statistical analysis.

I have approximately 11K discrete events and a corresponding score. I also have approximately 500 binary attributes. Each event is positive for one to six attributes. How do I go about trying to figure out the relationships between the variables and the score? What tool (open source preferred) should I use? Or is this really something I need to hire someone to do. I should note that I'm very good with Excel and do have a fair amount of programming experience.

Comment: Sounds like something well-suited to `R`, which meets your open source criterion... and you can get excellent assistance from the clever folk at http://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info

Comment: As Ben mentioned, such analyses can be performed using the open-source [**R Project**](http://www.r-project.org/). I’m not sure if I quite understand the nature of your analysis. Is the outcome (score?) of your events (data rows?) binary (i.e. positive or negative)? If so, you will need to apply multivariate logistic regression.

Comment: Hi there, could you give us some more information about your problem, e.g. the word "score" implies that some type of summation has been performed, but I'm not seeing how that is connected to your description of your predictors.

Comment: First, thanks to all for your responses.  By binary, I mean that attribute was present or not (e.g. did the person have red hair, did the person have a college degree, etc.).
The score is one column and the attributes are each individual columns.

Comment: @eAlchemist and what is the nature of the score variable? binary, ordinal, interval …?

Comment: It's interval.  There aren't really any bounds on the score, but it currently runs from approx -500 to 150.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer

Comment: I would encourage future posters to this answer to focus on how one would go about the actual statistical analysis. There is enough information here to go beyond just giving generic software recommendations. gmacfarlane's answer is a good start, but one could certainly provide more useful advice given the specific nature of the data and the task.

Answer (score 3):

[R](http://www.r-project.org/) is free and open source, and contains tools for just about any type of analysis you want to do. Excel is a spreadsheet, not a statistical software, so it is really not built to handle rigorous statistics on large datasets.

Given that you have programming experience, I think you will feel pretty comfortable in R once you get ahold of the syntax. You can start out with these commands, if you put your data in a `data.csv`.

```
mydata <- read.csv("data.csv")
corr(mydata)
model1 <- lm(Score ~ Other Variables, data = mydata)
summary(model1)
anova(model1)
```

Comment: The question of whether you should do it yourself or whether you should hire someone comes down to your statistical knowledge and the importance of the project.

Answer (score 1):

[Weka](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/) allows you to load data, and run many data mining algorithms on it, to find correlations between attributes and some output score.

It's quite sophisticated, and also open source.